# Unable to connect to the STOMP using stomp.js

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, postman, stomp, stompjs

```
var stompClient = Stomp.over(function () {
return sock;
});

console.log("before con");

stompClient.connect({}, () => {
    setConnected;
    stompClient.subscribe("/topic/hello", (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    });
    console.log("runnable");
});
```

this is the code where I tried to connect to STOMP and I GOT Following Log

```
LOG  before con
LOG  Opening Web Socket...
LOG  Web Socket Opened...
LOG  >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.2,1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000
```

But it does not recieve any message from the topic

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
//        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }


}
```

this is the springboot configuration I currently have

I tried using Postman by sending the Connect frame to the endpoint but no reply from the server.(Websocket connection was OK but only the STOMP connection gives me the headache)

```
CONNECT
accept-version:1.2
host:localhost

^@
```

this is the connect fram I have used