How to send stomp (websocket) message from postman to backend?
There is backend spring boot and stomp(protocol under websocket)
So, I used oficial example from git https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket
And started it. I cat use js client from the example and can send messages - everything okey


But I can't to send message from postman
Successful connection, but messages doen't send to backend(no responses and can't to catch execution under debug controller)


How to correct send messages via stomp using postman?

possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351993/unable-to-connect-to-the-stomp-using-stomp-js

You can send JSON message by Send Button with a specific channel.
Overview

Web Socket Server
Save as server.js
const express = require('express');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { join } = require('path');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a client connected');
    socket.emit('to_client', { message: 'Hello from server!' });

    // Listen a message from the client
    socket.on('to_server', (data) => {
        console.log('From client:', data);
        socket.emit('to_client', { message: `Server Received: ${JSON.stringify(data)}` });
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server running at http://localhost:3000');
});

Install dependencies
npm install express socket.io

Run server
node server.js


Client Config in Postman
URL
ws://localhost:3000

To server channel (or topic)
to_server

To server payload
{ "name": "Nick", "data": 1234 }

To client channel (or topic)
to_client


Connect Server by Postman

Server-side

Send Message by Postman

Server-side


There is error message when try to connect to backend using postman when choose socket.io
Could not connect to ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket
09:43:07
Error:{error}
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Request Method: GET

Can you try my server first?

With you server everything okey, but like additional question is postman doen't work with postman?

I try to connect with 'gs-messaging-stomp-websocket' by gradle bootRun. Browser open localhost:8080 works to send name and receive Greetings. I try to connect by Postman's WebSocket. It works send message and connection but It can't receive messages. Also I try to connect  socket.io as same as my answer but It makes an error to GET connection. I think STORM web socket protocol can't handle by Postman Socket.IO
